# Android: ObservableScrollView incorrect scrollY on device rotation

Tags: android, orientation-changes

I am using this library ObservableScrollView. I think it is pretty widely used and it is really good for animations for listview. But I am facing an issue with it.

Steps to reproduce:
1. Scroll the listview in Portrait mode.
2. Rotate the device to landscape mode.

Notice that scrollY value returned in the overriden method onScrollChanged() is not 0. Expected value is 0. I have filed an issue on github but no response. Has anyone else faced/resolved this issue. Please help. Thanks.